# Vuejs project build not working on server

Tags: npm, vuejs2, ubuntu-18.04

I have a vuejs2 project and I am developing it on Ubuntu. Now If I run `npm run build` on my development laptop and open "dist" folder from apache then the project works fine.

However, If I do the same on the server which is also an apache running on ubuntu then I get this error in browser's dev console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
at vendor.1b882bb6a097de1a309b.js:7
at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.1b882bb6a097de1a309b.js:7)
at vendor.1b882bb6a097de1a309b.js:7
at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.1b882bb6a097de1a309b.js:7)
at n (manifest.120bba3efdd853ace19c.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.8ebef1e6e8368062afd1.js:1)
at n (manifest.120bba3efdd853ace19c.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.8ebef1e6e8368062afd1.js:1)
at n (manifest.120bba3efdd853ace19c.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.8ebef1e6e8368062afd1.js:1)
```

the `npm run build` command was working fine until I've installed a new package and ran `npm install` on server.

Also when I ran `npm install` on server it said that there are some vulnerabilities and to fix them just run `npm audit fix --force` and I did so and all the vulnerabilities were gone. Since then whenever I run `npm run build` the project got successfully compiled. But when I open it in the browser I get the error mentioned above.

Also there were a memory issue while compiling the project but I managed to fix it by adding swap space on server and the project started to compiling successfully. But not opening in browser.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`? Are you transferring your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files to your server? Also, you don't need to build the project on the server; just upload the `dist` folder to your Apache document root

Comment: @Phil tried running `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`. But didn't solve my problem

Comment: By running `npm audit fix --force`, you modified the version of libraries you use. Maybe some of them have changed their syntax, causing this issue. You should review what did the audit command exactly did.